# How to get the user selected date from the RangeSelector in a Timeline of Vaadin Charts?

Tags: java, date, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-charts

The Vaadin Charts Timeline provides a RangeSelector that includes two textfields.
https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/charts/java-api/charts-timeline.html

These two textfields can be used to enter a custom date range fast.

The API of the [RangeSelector javadoc](https://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin/vaadin-charts/4.0.0/) does not seem to provide a method that provides access to the selection of the user, it does provides method that allow to format these text boxes.

Is there any alternative that makes it possible to get the dates that have been entered by the user in the input text fields of the RangeSelector in the server side using a java API?